# Empty SRC attributes and poor performance

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance

Recently I read this article by Nicholas C. Zakas:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/

It says that empty SRC attributes in IMG and SCRIPT files for example can cause poor performance. My question is:

Are there still the same performance issues if there is NO src attribute at all?

Example:

```
<img id="image" />
```

Also, how will the browser interpret this? Would the above code be problematic anywhere?

Much obliged for any help.

Comment: You are not allowed to have an `img` element with no `src` attribute in the first place, so I would say that it is potentially problematic *anywhere* it occurs. Regardless of whether there are performance issues or not you should strive to prevent that from happening as much as possible.

Comment: Now browsers is much more smarter then it were on "2009". Described problem do not exists on new browsers (tested).

Comment: thanks BoltClock - is that the W3 specification speaking there?

Comment: @user1360809: Yes, in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) the DTD explicitly lists the `src` attribute as required, and in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) it says "The src attribute must be present".

Comment: _“Described problem do not exists on new browsers”_ – and in an ideal world, where browsers were always up-to-date, that could maybe actually be a valid argument for using an `img` element without or with an empty `src` attribute …

Answer (score 0):

This is from [a very old version of the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html):

> SRC (Source)
>
> The SRC attribute specifies the URI for the image to be embedded. Its syntax is the same as that of the HREF attribute of the  tag. **SRC is mandatory.**

`@src` is required, so if you have an `<img>` with missing `@src`, then it wouldn't be a valid HTML. Browsers are very tolerant though, but what they will do in this situation is probably implementation specific.

EDIT: [from HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#attr-img-src):

> The **src attribute must be present**, and must contain **a valid non-empty URL** potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.

So, an `<img>` with missing or empty `@src` would not be valid HTML.

AFAIK, HTML 5 still does not specify how browsers should handle missing src attribute, although it did say:

> If the src attribute is not set and either the alt attribute is set to the empty string or the alt attribute is not set at all
>
> > The element represents nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose to quote an old, obsolete spec rather than the latest one, or at least one that's still in widespread use?

Comment: @BoltClock: No reason, just out of convenience. Since it's the one that shows up first in Google Search that's from W3C (others results that shows up are from w3schools and MDN), is that satisfactory? I'm pretty sure this aspect of img tag hasn't changed since back then.

Comment: So it turns out. I'm guessing one of your search terms was the word "mandatory" - it does indeed return the HTML 3.0 spec first (and not even the HTML 3.2 spec!), since it's the only one that uses that word.

Comment: @BoltClock: I've added some more quotes from HTML 5 spec, which, in retrospect, I should've done from the start.